# How to convert CSV data to PDF table using PDF::Table

Tags: perl, pdf

I need to convert CSV data into into a PDF table using Perl.

I've tried using [`PDF::API2`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Essimms/PDF-API2-2.031/lib/PDF/API2.pm) and [`PDF::Table`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eomega/PDF-Table-0.9.12/lib/PDF/Table.pm), but cannot achieve what I need.

Can anyone suggest what I have missed, or is there a better module to use?

#### CSV

[image]

#### Expected PDF Output

[image]

#### Actual output

[image]

#### My Perl code

```
use strict;

use lib '/data/fdr/scripts/irp/PDF-API2-2.031/lib';
use lib '/data/fdr/scripts/irp/PDF-Table-0.9.12/lib';

use PDF::API2;
use PDF::Table;

my %env_cfg;

my @inp_arg = @ARGV;

my ($ldlm,    $bid,     $lf,      $xf,      $hdrcnt,  $klm,  $sts,
    $iR,      $iC,      $od,      $lst,     $csv,     $cell, $hdr_seq,
    $key_cnt, $dat_rec, $dat_off, $dat_lmt, $len_cnt, $len_cnt1
) = ( '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0, 0, '', '', '', '', 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0 );

my ( $worksheet, $workbook, $fxls, $keyhdr, $dathdr, $dat_cnt, $csvcol )
        = ( '', '', '', '', '', 0, 0 );

my @csv_rcd = ( '' );

my $header   = '';
my $data     = '';
my $somedata = [];
my $cellval  = '';

my $testfile = "/data/fdr/scripts/config_file/test.txt";

$sts = open( CSV, "< /data/fdr/output/IRP/FILING/1/Misc_Symbols.csv" );

if ( $sts == 0 ) {

    print LOG tmstmp() . ": Error opening CSV file Misc_Symbols.csv\n";
    print LOG "$ldlm\n";

    next;
}

my $pdftable = new PDF::Table;
my $pdf      = PDF::API2->new();
my $page     = $pdf->page();

$page->mediabox( 'A4' );

my $font = $pdf->corefont( 'Helvetica-Bold' );
my $text = $page->text();

$text->textstart;
$text->font( $font, 12 );
$text->translate( 200, 700 );

$iR = -1;
$iC = 0;

while ( <CSV> ) {

    $iR++;
    $iC = 0;    # This is the column co-ordinate for the excel file

    $csvcol = -1;    # This is the column co-ordinate for the csv file
    $csv    = $_;

    chomp( $csv );

    $cellval = '';
    @csv_rcd = split( ',', $csv );

    foreach $cell ( @csv_rcd ) {

        $csvcol++;

        if ( ( ${cell} ne '*' ) ) {

            if ( $iR <= 5 ) {
                $text->lead( 10 );
                $text->section( "${cell}", 500, 800 );
            }
            else {
                $cellval = $cellval . $cell;
                push( @$somedata, [ $cellval . ',' ] );

            }

        }
        
        $iC++;
    }

}

close CSV;

$pdftable->table(

    # required params
    $pdf,
    $page,
    $somedata,

    x       => 50,
    w       => 495,
    start_y => 792,
    next_y  => 700,
    start_h => 400,
    next_h  => 500,

    # some optional params
    border          => 1,
    font_size       => 20,
    max_word_length => 20,
    padding         => 5,
    row_height      => 30,

    column_props    => [
        {},    # no properties for the first column
        {   min_w            => 250,
            justify          => "right",
            font             => $pdf->corefont( "Times", -encoding => "latin1" ),
            font_size        => 14,
            font_color       => 'white',
            background_color => '#8CA6C5',
        },
    ],
);

$text->textend;
$pdf->saveas( "Sample3.pdf" );
$pdf->end();
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and fix the code markup.

Comment: Why did you not install PDF::API2? Looks like you just downloaded and unpacked an archive, but didn't really install. Anyway, making PDF::Table do formatted stuff is... tricky. I've used it maybe 8 years ago, but can't really remember. Since your expected output looks like an Excel file, have you considered creating an XLS(X) and then using something else to convert that to PDF?

Comment: what is `tmstmp`? You have this line `print LOG tmstmp() [...]` but `tmstmp` is not defined as far as I can see

Comment: Please don't post text information as an image. We to see the original CSV data to be able to try things for ourselves.

Comment: Please *always* `use warnings 'all'` as well as `use strict` in *every* Perl program that you write. Also, it is much better not to declare every variable at the start of the file. Variables should be declared as close as possible to where they are first used so that Perl can discard them when they are no longer required. In particular, long lists of declarations and corresponding definitions like that are very unclear, and there's rarely a need to define Perl variables anyway.

Comment: `if ( $sts == 0 ) { ... }` will raise a warning, because `open` returns `undef` in case of a failure, not zero. If you must test the result separately then use `unless ( $sts ) { ... }`. Together with the missing `tmstmp` that **Håkon Hægland** identified, I suspect that you haven't posted your real code. Without that we can't help you.

Comment: You don't use any of these variables  `$bid`, `$lf`, `$xf`, `$hdrcnt`, `$klm`, `$od`, `$lst`, `$hdr_seq`, `$key_cnt`, `$dat_rec`, `$dat_off`, `$dat_lmt`, `$len_cnt`, `$len_cnt1` so they shouldn't be declared.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the problem is this line:

```
push( @$somedata, [  $cellval .',' ] );
```

which generates an `N x 1` matrix `$somedata`. You need an `N x M` matrix `$somedata`. So you should instead create a row array `@rowdata` in the inner `foreach` loop:

```
push @rowdata, $cellval;
```

and, at the bottom of the outer `while` loop you can do

```
push @$somedata, \@rowdata;
```

This gives the following loops:

```
while ( my $csv = <$CSV> ) {

    chomp $csv;

    ++$iR;
    $iC = 0;         # This is the column co-ordinate for the Excel file

    my $csvcol = -1; # This is the column co-ordinate for the CSV file
    my $cellval = '';
    @csv_rcd = split /,/, $csv;

    my @rowdata;

    foreach my $cell ( @csv_rcd ) {

        ++$csvcol;

        if ( $cell ne '*' ) {

            if ( $iR <= 5 ) {
                $text->lead( 10 );
                $text->section( $cell, 500, 800 );
            }
            else {
                push @rowdata, $cell;
            }
        }

        $iC++;
    }

    push @$somedata, \@rowdata;
}
```

Comment: We tried this option but it is not producing the expected o/p. Also we want to create a array value like [['Symbol - Test','BI - Test','PD - Test','PIP - Test','UM - Test','COMP - Test','COLL - Test'],['66','.8500','.8500','1.1600','1.1600']] then only we can able to use this in PDF::Table, So can you please help on this as i am new to this PDF::Table & Perl i am struggling to achieve this, Can you please help me on this. Thanks in Advance.